PyTorch Lightning with T5 Model - RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
Despite setting requires_grad=True for all parameters, the decoder_hidden_states and so on. do not seem to propagate gradients, resulting in a RuntimeError during training.
I am currently facing an issue with the T5ForConditionalGeneration model from Hugging Face's Transformers library, integrated into a PyTorch Lightning framework.
Error message is below:
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[208], line 26
     23 trainer = make_trainer(max_epochs=max_epochs, name='test', patience=patience,)
     25 try:
---> 26     trainer.fit(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader)
     27 except KeyError as e:
     28     print(f"KeyError: {e}")

File c:\Users\foo\anaconda3\envs\p100_venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py:531, in Trainer.fit(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    529 model = _maybe_unwrap_optimized(model)
    530 self.strategy._lightning_module = model
--> 531 call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
    532     self, self._fit_impl, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path
    533 )

File c:\Users\foo\anaconda3\envs\p100_venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\call.py:42, in _call_and_handle_interrupt(trainer, trainer_fn, *args, **kwargs)
     40     if trainer.strategy.launcher is not None:
     41         return trainer.strategy.launcher.launch(trainer_fn, *args, trainer=trainer, **kwargs)
---> 42     return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     44 except _TunerExitException:
     45     _call_teardown_hook(trainer)

File c:\Users\foo\anaconda3\envs\p100_venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py:570, in Trainer._fit_impl(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    560 self._data_connector.attach_data(
...
    272     allow_unreachable=True,
    273     accumulate_grad=True,
    274 )

RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Dataset and Model is below:
###### Dataset #####
class WrimeDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, tokenizer, max_length):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.data = dataframe
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text = self.data.iloc[idx]['input_text']
        row = self.data.iloc[idx]
        labels = row['label'] 

        # 入力テキストの前処理
        inputs = self.tokenizer(
            "感情分析：" + text,
            max_length=self.max_length,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors="pt"
        )

        input_ids = inputs['input_ids'].squeeze().to(dtype=torch.long)
        attention_mask = inputs['attention_mask'].squeeze().to(dtype=torch.long)

        labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)
        # shape: torch.Size([8])
        
        padding_sign = torch.full((self.max_length,), -100, dtype=torch.long)
        actual_length = min(len(inputs), self.max_length)
        padding_sign[:actual_length] = input_ids[:actual_length]

        return input_ids, attention_mask, padding_sign, labels


##### Model #####
class T5Model(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(T5Model, self).__init__()
        model_name = "sonoisa/t5-base-japanese"
        config = T5Config.from_pretrained(model_name, output_hidden_states=True)
        self.t5_model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name, config=config)
        self.tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
        self.acc = Accuracy(task="multiclass", num_classes=num_classes)
        self.f1 = F1Score(task="multiclass", num_classes=num_classes)
        self.qwk = CohenKappa(task="multiclass", num_classes=num_classes, weights='quadratic')
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(config.d_model, num_classes)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

        for param in self.t5_model.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True

        for param in self.classifier.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True
        

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, labels=None):
        labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)
        output = self.t5_model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
        loss = output.loss
        decoder_hidden_states = output.decoder_hidden_states
        last_decoder_state = decoder_hidden_states[-1][:, -1, :]
        logits = self.classifier(last_decoder_state)
        probs = self.sigmoid(logits)
        print("Loss requires_grad:", loss.requires_grad)
        print("Decoder Hidden States requires_grad:", output.decoder_hidden_states[-1].requires_grad)
        print("Logits requires_grad:", logits.requires_grad) 
        return loss, probs, logits
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        input_ids, attention_mask, padding, labels = batch
        loss, probs, logits = self.forward(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        input_ids, attention_mask, padding, labels = batch
        loss, probs, logits = self.forward(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)

        input_ids, attention_mask, padding, labels = batch
        
        self.acc.update(probs, labels.bool())
        self.f1.update(probs, labels.bool())
        self.qwk.update(probs, labels.bool())
        
        self.log('val_loss', loss)
        
    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
        self.log('val_acc', self.acc.compute(), on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log('val_f1', self.f1.compute(), on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log('val_qwk', self.qwk.compute(), on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        # メトリクスをリセット
        self.acc.reset()
        self.f1.reset()
        self.qwk.reset()

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = Adafactor(
            self.parameters(),
            scale_parameter=True,
            relative_step=True,
            warmup_init=True,
            lr=None)  # Adafactorはlrを自動的に調整する
        return optimizer

Returns are
Loss requires_grad: False
Decoder Hidden States requires_grad: False
Logits requires_grad: False

Steps Already Tried

Ensured requires_grad=True is set for all model parameters.
Checked the loss, decoder_hidden_states, logits directly to ensure they should propagate gradients.
Reviewed and tried solutions from similar issues related to gradient propagation problems in PyTorch but found no resolution.

Can anyone help identify why decoder_hidden_states etc do not require grad or suggest what changes should be made to the code to ensure gradients are propagated correctly?

I solved it myself.
I upgrade version of pytorch-lightning from 2.0.3 to 2.2.2.
Then, this problem is solved.
